# I am trying to communicate to a movie clip in an external SWF file in AS3 and getting an error 1050

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

Okay, so in AS3, CS4, I am trying to communicate with a movie clip in an external SWF.  I can communicate with one of the movie clips: backunit1game2_mc (it does what I want), but I am not being able to communicate with next3_mc.  I get the following error: unloadmovie
TypeError: Error #1010: A term is undefined and has no properties.
    at Game3Unit1_Scene1_fla::MainTimeline/unMovieLoad()
unload

I have exported next3_mc as an ActionScript file.  Furthermore, I can't seem to export any movie clip in any other flash program and redo what I did with backunit1game2_mc.  Is there something I could be doing wrong when I am trying to export?  Please help!!!I have the following code:

```
var loadedSWF:Loader = null;

/**
 * Loads an SWF and adds it to container once complete
 * @param file The URL to the SWF to load
 * @param container The container to add the SWF to
 */
function loadSWF(file:String, container:MovieClip=null):void
{
    if(container == null) container = MovieClip(root);

    // removes the previously loaded SWF
    if(loadedSWF != null)
    {
        if(loadedSWF.parent) loadedSWF.parent.removeChild(loadedSWF);
    }

    var req:URLRequest = new URLRequest(file);
    loadedSWF = new Loader();
    loadedSWF.load(req);

    addChild(loadedSWF);


}

nextunit1game1_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, _click);
function _click(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    loadSWF("game3unit1game2.swf");
    loadedSWF.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, unMovieLoad);
}


function unMovieLoad(event:Event):void
{

    trace("unloadmovie");

    /* In order to be able to access a movie clip in an external SWF
    file, you must first export that for use in the other file.  Right click on 
    the movie clip, select properties, and export to AS file.  */

    /*  Here we are making the menu button return us to the main menu.*/

    event.target.content.backunit1game2_mc.buttonMode = true;
    event.target.content.backunit1game2_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, returnTogame1);
    event.target.content.next3_mc.buttonMode = true;
    //event.target.content.nextunit1game2_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, goTogame3);

}


function returnTogame1(event:MouseEvent):void
{

    //this.parent.parent.parent.removeChild(bgLoader);

    /* This unloads the movie */

    removeChild(loadedSWF);
    trace("unload");
}
```

Comment: is backunit1game2_mc on the stage of the SWF you're loading in frame 1, and also set to Export for Actionscript, and also named the same thing in the properties window (its instance name) when you select it on stage of that FLA file?

Comment: Yes to all of the above for both backunit1game2_mc and next3_mc.  What's troubling me is that backunit1game2_mc actually works but next3_mc doesn't.  I have done, I think, the same thing both times.  Since the code is the same, it must be something in the export, I would think, but I can't figure out why the export for next3_mc won't work.  I've also redone this with two other games, (games 3 and 4), and I can't get the back button to work then, even though I literally copied and pasted the code, changing only the instance names. Can there be something wrong with the export for as in settings?